# don't work ( where... and...) in sql

Tags: php, mysqli

its all code

```
    <?php
$subject;
$query="SELECT * ";
$query.="FROM SUBJECTS ";
$query.="WHERE VISIBLE = 1 ";
$query.="ORDER BY POSITION ASC"; 
$subject_set=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
Confrim_query($subject_set);
?>
<?php
while($subject=mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_set)){?>
    <li><?php echo $subject["MENU_NAME"] . "(".$subject["ID"].")"; ?>
    <?php  }?>
    <?php
$query="SELECT * ";
$query .="FROM PAGES ";
$query .="WHERE VISIBLE = 1 ";
$query .="AND SUBJECT_ID = {$subject['ID']"} ;
$query .="ORDER BY POSITION ASC";
$page_set=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
Confrim_query($page_set);

?>
```

but part this code no Run and no show in page

```
   <ul class="page">
    <?php
    while($page=mysqli_fetch_assoc($page_set)){ ?>
    <li><?php echo $page["MENU_NAME"] ?></li>
    <?php }?>
    <?php mysqli_free_result($page_set); ?>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <?php  mysqli_free_result($subject_set);  ?>

    </ul>
```

when add the this :

> $query .="AND SUBJECT_ID = {$subject['ID']"} ;

this part can't reload database and failed.

Comment: `$query .="AND SUBJECT_ID = {$subject['ID']} ";`... `}` outside of the quotes

Comment: Double quotes are at wrong place. Try with this : `$query .="AND SUBJECT_ID = {$subject['ID']}";`

Comment: please try to make the English clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FIND THE ANSWER....WHAT IS PROBLEM
after

```
while ($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_set))
{?>
<li><?PHP echo $subject['MENU_NAME'] . "(" . $subject['ID'] . ")";
```

must be add query

```
$query = "SELECT * ";
$query .= "FROM PAGES ";
$query .= "WHERE SUBJECT_ID={$subject['ID']} ";
$query .= "ORDER BY SUBJECT_ID ASC ";
$page_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
Confrim_query($page_set);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a curly bracket inside the string in front of `$subject['ID']` and one outside of the string.
I don't think that you need the curly brackets to make the query work, try to remove  them and see if it works.

```
SELECT * FROM PAGES WHERE VISIBLE = 1 AND SUBJECT_ID = $subject['ID'] ORDER BY POSITION ASC;
```

Comment: Do you get any SQL error (`mysqli_error($connection)`)?

Comment: That wouldn't work because if `$subject['ID']`. I believe there is a problem with the command in general.

Comment: thanx for help.

Comment: @Julianv.dBerkmortel no have error.i dont correct  programming.thanx for answer